# How to do a power analysis for a virtual species distrubition model which uses random forests

Tags: random-forest, sample-size, statistical-power

I am creating virtual species distributions on a 100x100 grid (for now). Each layer of the grid represents one environmental variable. The "suitability function" defines the probability of a presence (and inversely, an absence) at a given point based on the value of each variable (grid layer). Stratified random sampling is used. Actual probabilities are used (using Bernoulli trials), rather than the threshold approach (where all probabilities above, say 70%, are set to true). The sampling and determination of whether a point is a presence or absence is done in the same step (so detection is perfect). Random forests are used to create a species distribution model (SDM).

Is there a way to do a power analysis which tells you what sample size you need to achieve some measurable metric, such as AUC-ROC or Brier score (or other type of metric)?

Comment: Did you search for methods to do this using a simulation method?

Comment: Yes. I saw mention that you can do it that way for some other use cases.